# Custom URL segment parameters for posts

Tags: url-rewriting, parameter

I need to add a custom parameter/segment to the post URL.

For example, when I have a post at `example.com/post-name`, I need to add another segment like `example.com/post-name/places`. After that, I need to add a dynamic segment like `example.com/post-name/places/dynamic-value`.

I can't use `?key=value` parameters, it needs to be segmented. I've tried to work with `add_rewrite_rule()`, but it doesn't seem to work.

How can I achieve something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought of making post type, taxonomy, terms?

If you do so, it will be a lot easier for you to code and get the above urls.

If any confusion, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I actualy managed to do that with add_rewrite_rule();
just before add_rewrite_rule() you need to use flush_rewrite_rules() function, and it works.